# Objective-C C Style Functions

Tags: objective-c, c

When doing objective-c, do I have to write out functions like:

```
- (int) someFunction: (int) a someParam: (int) b;
```

Or can I use regular C style:

```
void someFunction(int a, int b);
```

If I can do the C style, is there any benefit to doing it in the Objective-C style?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use regular C functions, if you like, since Objective-C is just a super set of C.

You need to use Objective-C syntax if you want to use Objective-C features, like classes, messages, inheritance, etc... and of course to use the Cocoa/CocoaTouch SDK.

You can mix Objective-C and C code in your files, and have an Objective-C method call out to a pure C function. You can also call an Objective-C method from a pure C function by accessing directly the Objective-C runtime layer (e.g., using the `objc_msgSend` function).

Answer (score 9):

That's not an Objective-C function, it's a method.  It's got access to an instance's variables and other methods.  The two are not equivalent.  In most cases you should use an Objective-C method.  Why do you want to use C functions?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I was confused by the int main(int argc, char *argv[]) declaration being in C style, but then after reading sergio's response, I forgot that C can't do classes (I went C++ -> C# now to Objective-C), so Objective-C's way of declaring classes is the @interface and the funky method name splitting. Thanks, you've both cleared this up.

Comment: If you know C++, you may also be interested in the fact that by naming your source files with an `.mm` extension instead of an `.m` extension they compile as Objective-C++. You get the Objective-C syntax on top of C++ instead of on top of C. And with recent versions of the compiler you also get a lot of C++11 features (not sure if you get all yet as I'm not a guru of C++11).

Answer (score 1):

The first statement is a method declaration the second statement is a function. They are 2 things completely unrelated. Both are accepted in objective-C. But the method declaration can only happen in between an `@interface` `@end`. And a function declaration cannot happen in between `@interface` `@end`

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two is the difference between a generic method and an instance method. The first example is a generic method. It can be called from anywhere (as long as the compiler can find it) and does not require an instance of any objects. If you have used methods like CGPointMake(x,y), these are set up as generic (C style) methods.

```
someFunction(4,5);
```

The second type is an instance method. It is defined only inside one class, and the - at the beginning means you must have an instance of this class to call the method. So

```
Foo *myFoo = [[Foo alloc] init];
[myFoo someFunction:4 someParam:5];
```

I tend to use the first style for simple utility methods that don't necessarily belong to one class or another, such as math or point manipulation methods. Most of your methods should probably be instance methods, but that is a longer answer (object oriented design).